# Is there a reason why this flutter code isn't working?

Tags: android, flutter, dart

I put the default flutter code in the same lib folder, with a different name and haven't used it. When I replace my code with the default code, the counter button works, but the button in my code doesn't work.
I think the problem is with how my my code deals with states. What should I do?

Also, any tips on how I can reload certain widgets, and not the whole app?

Code:

```
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';

void main() {
  runApp(MyApp());
}

class MyApp extends StatelessWidget {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return MaterialApp(
      home: MyHomePage(),
    );
  }
}

class MyHomePage extends StatefulWidget {
  @override
  _MyHomePageState createState() => _MyHomePageState();
}

class _MyHomePageState extends State<MyHomePage> {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    int _incrementCounter = 0;

    void _increment() {
      setState(() {
        _incrementCounter++;
      });
    }

    return Scaffold(
      appBar: AppBar(
        title: Text('My First App!'),
        backgroundColor: Colors.red[800],
      ),
      body: Container(
        child: Center(
          child: Column(
            mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.center,
            children: <Widget>[
              Text(
                'You pressed the button this many times:',
                style: TextStyle(
                  fontSize: 18,
                ),
              ),
              SizedBox(height: 10),
              Text(
                '$_incrementCounter',
                style: TextStyle(
                  fontSize: 48,
                ),
              ),
            ],
          ),
        ),
      ),
      floatingActionButton: FloatingActionButton(
        onPressed: _increment,
        tooltip: 'Increment Counter',
        backgroundColor: Colors.red[800],
        child: Icon(
          Icons.add,
        ),
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

Any help is appreciated!

Comment: welcome to SO, please be thorough on the problem you are facing, like code snippets error snippets etc

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You've put the `_incrementeCounter` varaible into state class. Every time you called `setState`, state re built and your counter variable reset to initial value.

Move the `_incrementCounter` field to the `MyHomePage` widget and access it from the `state` class like `widget._incrementCounter`. It will work.
Full code:

```
void main() {
  runApp(MyApp());
}

class MyApp extends StatelessWidget {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return MaterialApp(
      home: MyHomePage(),
    );
  }
}

class MyHomePage extends StatefulWidget {
  int _incrementCounter = 0;

  @override
  _MyHomePageState createState() => _MyHomePageState();
}

class _MyHomePageState extends State<MyHomePage> {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    void _increment() {
      setState(() {
        widget._incrementCounter++;
      });
    }

    return Scaffold(
      appBar: AppBar(
        title: Text('My First App!'),
        backgroundColor: Colors.red[800],
      ),
      body: Container(
        child: Center(
          child: Column(
            mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.center,
            children: <Widget>[
              Text(
                'You pressed the button this many times:',
                style: TextStyle(
                  fontSize: 18,
                ),
              ),
              SizedBox(height: 10),
              Text(
                '${widget._incrementCounter}',
                style: TextStyle(
                  fontSize: 48,
                ),
              ),
            ],
          ),
        ),
      ),
      floatingActionButton: FloatingActionButton(
        onPressed: _increment,
        tooltip: 'Increment Counter',
        backgroundColor: Colors.red[800],
        child: Icon(
          Icons.add,
        ),
      ),
    );
  }
}
```